# node leave left side screen enter opposite side of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-motion

oke so i have the following code that makes my skspritenode move on the x-axis see the code below:

```
manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
        (data, error) in

        let currentX = self.Player.position.x

        if data!.acceleration.x < 0 {
            self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 1000)
        }

        else if data!.acceleration.x > 0 {
            self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 1000)
        }

        print(currentX)
    }

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    let action = SKAction.moveToX(destX, duration: 0.1)
    self.Player.runAction(action)
}
```

now when the skspritenode leaves the left or right of the screen i want it to reappear on the other side of the screen. i tried adding the following line code:

```
else if currentX >= self.size.width-5 {
            self.destX = 5
        }
```

but this sadly didnt work. could someone explain me how to do this?

oke so this is how the update function looks now:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */


    let action = SKAction.moveToX(destX, duration: 0.1)
    self.Player.runAction(action)

    if self.Player.position.x < CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - (Player.size.width / 2) {

        self.player.position.x = CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - (self.Player.size.width / 2)

    }

    else if self.Player.position.x > CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + (Player.size.width / 2) {

        self.player.position.x = CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + (self.Player.size.width / 2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to the player and the screen why dont you add something like this into the update method

```
 if self.Player.position.x < CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - (Player.size.width / 2) {

    self.player.position.x = CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - (self.Player.size.width / 2)

} 

else if self.Player.position.x > CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + (Player.size.width / 2) {

    self.player.position.x = CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + (self.Player.size.width / 2)
}
```

I tried to get it to work with your moving code but I couldn't, think its the SKAction in the updateMethod.

Try this instead.

Create this above your GameScene class underneath the import SpriteKit line

```
 struct PhysicsCategory {
     static let player: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
     static let enemy: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
 }
```

to create your physics categories. If you are unsure about this read some tutorials about SKPhysicsBodies, there are plenty on the web. Sooner or later you will have to anyway.

Now give you player a physics body. Go to where you are creating your player and add this code just before adding it to scene.

```
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.player
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    addChild(player)
```

and change your motion code to this

```
 manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
    (data, error) in

     /// use this to limit the max speed of player in both directions
     guard player.physicsBody!.velocity.dx > -500 && node.physicsBody!.velocity.dx < 500 else { return }

    /// if your game is in landscape
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft {
            self.player.physicsBody!.applyForce(CGVectorMake(-500 * CGFloat(data!.acceleration.y), 0))
        } else {
           self.player.physicsBody!.applyForce(CGVectorMake(500 * CGFloat(data!.acceleration.y), 0))
        }


    /// if your game is in portrait
        self.player.physicsBody!.applyForce(CGVectorMake(500 * CGFloat(data!.acceleration.y), 0))
}
```

Comment out the code that you dont need depending on your orientation.
Play around with the 500 value to get your desired speed.

Hope this helps

Comment: ok thanks you for the answer but a quick question. (i am quite new to coding). the let variable before accelerationData gives an error. the error says the following:  Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CMAcceleration'.

Comment: Hey, yeah sorry, try replacing the ! in the statement with a ?. Otherwise maybe just get rid of it, is was a suggestion. Is the screen stuff working?

Comment: no :(  I added your code but it didnt do anything ill update my question to show you how i implemented your code maybe it is an error from my side

Comment: Cool, I will have a look.

Comment: Whats happening when your character goes off screen

Comment: it just keeps going that direction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106107/discussion-between-crashoverride777-and-futurecake).

Comment: cashoverride777 you are the real MVP it works :D thank you soooo much <3

Comment: sorry to ask but i have one more question about solution the player is now dynamic. so if i tilt the device to the right the movement speed gets faster and faster because it is sort of adding up because of the physics. is there a way to keep the speed constant??

Comment: No problem. You want the sensitivity, thats the whole point of the motion. I normally set a max speed just above the motion code so that he will never move faster than a certain speed. I update the answer. You have to play around with the values

Comment: oke great that fixed my problem! but now a new problem has come up :( when the player is moving to the right at its max speed of 500. it taks a couple of seconds for the player to change direction if you tilt the screen to the left. is there a way to make the movement change from direction instantly? so if you were moving the player right and you change the tilt of your screen to the left and then player instantly goes moving left?

Comment: Well you are dealing with apples physics engine so I am not 100% sure an instant change is possible. You first should play around with this value "manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1". Set it even lower, to like 0.001 or something to get faster updates.

Comment: ok i set it to like 0.0001 but it still didn't fix the problem. the original movement code i posted works great for the last problem... isn't there a way to merge my original code with your code. because i think the whole physics thing isn't really getting the desired result.. :(

Comment: I will play around with your old code tomorrow. Maybe try your old code but in the update method where the code is to change side call "removeAllActions" before changing side

Answer (score 0):

oke so i figured it out so it is just the way i want it:

with all the help of crashoverride777 i came to the following solution:
so i put an if statement around the action code so it would only fire when in the bounds of the screen and if it isnt in the bounds of the screen crashoverrides code would start running.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    print(self.Player.position.x)

    if (self.Player.position.x > CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)-5) && (self.Player.position.x < CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)+5){

        let action = SKAction.moveToX(self.destX, duration: 1)
        self.Player.runAction(action)

    }
```

so i added crashoverrides code to the update function see below:

```
    if self.Player.position.x < CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - (Player.size.width / 2) {

        self.Player.position.x = CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)
    }

    else if self.Player.position.x > CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + (Player.size.width / 2) {

        self.Player.position.x = CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)         }
}
```